# How to find a cell with same special character twice?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a list A1:A4000 want to sort or find cells having special character '@' two times in one cell.

Comment: And what have you already tried / achieved, dude?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your question is very low quality. This is a Q & A site, so you need to ask a specific question. Please provide details of what you have attempted so far and where you have gotten stuck. `Sorting` and `finding` are two different things in Excel. Please explain what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: In my excel sheet there is one coloum with  e-mail ids I want to find cells with special Character '@' two times.
I want to find cells with two E-mail Ids. as I want to keep one e-mail id in one cell.

Comment: Your question comes across like " I have done no work, or research, I just want you guys to do my work for me" -  I'm sure this isn't the case but it's best to show what you've done :) ... As it is, it is unclear what you want and it's too broad and will likely be closed...

Answer (score 3):

I respect duDE's comment but I have this handy:

**Add extra column with this formula. This assumes the first value is in A2**

```
=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"@",""))
```

You can then sort by this new column to give you the number of occurrences

Comment: Change the ; to ,. You might be using older Excel

Comment: It basically takes the length of the original text and minus the length of the  text without the @

Comment: `;` didn't work in 2010 (which is what the OP has), updated your post to use `,` - IMO this is a better answer than mine, +1

Comment: In Excel 2010 you need to use , not ;

Comment: As in =LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"@",""))

Comment: Yes Shaun, you need to use `,` and since the OP is using Excel 2010, the question should be for Excel 2010 :)

Answer (score 1):

This will do it

```
Option Explicit
Sub Sigh()

Dim row As Integer
row = 1                        'UPDATE THIS FROM 1 TO THE FIRST ROW
Do While (Range("A" & row).Value <> "")

    Dim occurances As Integer
    occurances = StringCountOccurrences(Range("A" & row).Value, "@")
    If (occurances > 1) Then
        Range("B" & row).Value = "Yes"
    End If

row = row + 1
Loop

End Sub

Function StringCountOccurrences(strText As String, strFind As String, _
                                Optional lngCompare As VbCompareMethod) As Long
'copied from http://codevba.com/visual-basic-source-code/vb-string/count_occurrences_in_a_string.htm#.VbIjzyty3OQ
Dim lngPos As Long
Dim lngTemp As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
    If Len(strText) = 0 Then Exit Function
    If Len(strFind) = 0 Then Exit Function
    lngPos = 1
    Do
        lngPos = InStr(lngPos, strText, strFind, lngCompare)
        lngTemp = lngPos
        If lngPos > 0 Then
            lngCount = lngCount + 1
            lngPos = lngPos + Len(strFind)
        End If
    Loop Until lngPos = 0
    StringCountOccurrences = lngCount
End Function
```